# Testing HealthKit without paying Apple

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, healthkit

I'm looking to try to write an app to help my wife out with moving some data around into HealthKit.

Is there a way I can use Xcode and/or Xamarian to gain access to the HealthKit SDK without having the App ID or how can I create an App ID without spending the $99? I'd like to experiment first without paying up.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xcode Preferences, click on accounts, and add your apple ID. Do not sign into the [developer website](http://developer.apple.com/). If you have, save the XCode file somewhere and delete the XCode APPLICATION. Redownload from the Mac Store and as soon as it starts, open preferences and add your Apple ID.

Comment: I tried that and it won't run the app in the simulator.

Comment: @DanielA.White Did it work for you? Tested again, worked again.